# replace the class with new class without keeping the Newclass same where ever we are taking that from

Tags: jquery, replace, replacewith

I want to replace the code with new code. I used replaceWith to replace the function.But it removes the new class from where it was before . I want that class to stay in where ever it was before and need to replace the another class. How to do it??
Ex:
$('.popinner').insertAfter($('.rContentPopUp'));
when I do this".rContentPopUp" is replacing the 'popinner' class. BUt ".rContentPopUp" was removed from old structure where ever it was there.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can pass a class name to the removeClass function eg...

$('#element name').removeClass('classToRemove');

doing this will just remove that class from the element leaving all existing classes.  Then you can simply call addClass to add in your new class.  I believe this is what you want to do?